# How do I fix an ACL2 books sanity check failure?

Tags: acl2

From within the ACL2 books directory, whenever I try to build or clean the books, I get an error message that looks like:

`GNUmakefile:299: *** Books Sanity Check Failed.  Stop.`

How can I avoid this error message?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the makefile now checks that the acl2 make thinks you're using is the same as the directory you're currently in.  The solution is to tell make to use the acl2 that is in your current directory.  You can achieve this by passing in ACL2 as an argument to make, e.g.:

`make ACL2=~/sw/acl2-extra/saved_acl2 clean`